# How to update partial data without loading the html in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload partial view data without reloading the html. i have used `Json` to get the data but I think there is some issues in Script. The `Success` part is not executing.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult HorseTracker(ClsHorseTracker model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                  horseTrackerDetails.InsertUpdateHorseTracker(model);
                    }
                                        }
                return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }

 [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult HorseTrackerDetails()
        {
            return PartialView("_pHorseTrackerDetails", horseTrackerDetails.HorseTrackerList());
        }
```

Main View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("HorseTracker", "HorseTracker", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateForm" }))
        {
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="font-size:12px;">

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">    

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HorseName)

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HorseTypeName, Model.HorseTypeList)

                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                </div>
            </div>

        }

    </div>
    <div id="partial" class="col-md-8">
        @Html.Action("HorseTrackerDetails", "HorseTracker")
    </div>
```

Partial View

```
  <table class="table">
                <tr>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HorseName)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Type")
                    </th>


                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            @item.HorseName
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @item.HorseTypeName
                        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("HorseTracker", "HorseTracker")';
            $('#CreateForm').submit(function () {

                  if (!$(this).valid()) {
                    return;
                   }
                 $.post(url,$(this).serialize(), function (response) {
                     if (response.success) {
                         debugger;
                         $('#partial').html(response);
                     }
                     else {
                         var message = response.message;
                         alert(message);
                      }
                });
                   return false;
               })
        })
```

Comment: You're returning `model` (`ClsHorseTracker`) but not includes `success` response, hence `if (response.success)` always returns false. You need to add something like `success = true` in `return Json` part.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, now `$('#partial').html(response);` executes but still do not see changes in the form unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Check if `response` returns proper HTML partial page response. If it returns something other than HTML markups, you should know why the response is not rendered properly.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, When I mousehover on `html`, it doesnot show markup. But response contains data inside. Where I am doing wrong.Please guide me.

Comment: Well, you should use `return PartialView` instead of `return Json` on successful result with viewmodel - you only need to check if the request fails with `success = false` exist as response.

Comment: In the controller it needs to be `return Json(new { success = true, data = model });` and the in the `success` callback, `if (response.success) { // read the property values from response.data and update the corresponding form controls }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your comment. I will try and see now.

Comment: But its unclear what model properties you are changing in your controller method - if you not changing any, then you do not need to do anything in the `if (response.success)` block of code (because there is nothing to update)

Comment: Note that `$('#partial').html(response)` must returns partial view - using `data = model` will probably not containing partial view since it just returning viewmodel contents into response, not full partial view markup.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, As you have seen the view, I am giving some input and saving it which should reflect in the partial view. The functionality at backend is working. The data is getting saved in the database but not updated in the partial. But If refresh it then t will show the updated data.

Comment: All you need to do is return `Json(true);` or (`false` if there is an error). Then in the `success` callback, all you need to do is `if(response)` - if its true, then create a new `<tr>` element, add the `<td>` elements based on the values on the form and then `.append()` it to the `<table>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you please show me how to create an element and append it to the table. Appreciated, if you could provide an answer for this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are changing the values of you model properties is the POST method, then there is no reason to return the model (or a partial view). You can simply append a new row to the table based on the values in your form.

Your controller method should be

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult HorseTracker(ClsHorseTracker model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
              horseTrackerDetails.InsertUpdateHorseTracker(model);
              return Json(new { success = true});
        }
        // see notes below
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(new { message = "your error message" });
    }
}
```

Then modify the script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("HorseTracker", "HorseTracker")';
$('#CreateForm').submit(function () {
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }
    var name = $('#HorseName').val();
    var type = $('#HorseTypeName').find('option:selected').text()

    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');
            row.append($('<td></td>').text(name));
            row.append($('<td></td>').text(type));
            $('.table').append(row);
        } else if (response.message) {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

Notes

If `ModelState` is not valid, then you should return a list of `ModelState` errors, so that you can update the corresponding element generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(...);` To do that you can use

```
var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });
return Json( new { errors = errors });
```

and then add a `else if (response.errors) { // update the error messages }` block of code in the `success` callback

If would be better to render the `<table>` with `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements and give the `<tbody>` an `id` attribute and use that as the selector to add the new row

Comment: Currently for `var name = $('#HorseName');` giving `[object Object]`

Comment: One more thing to ask, as main is providing criteria and based on that criteria, more than 2 fields are inserting in the database. In that case,if I want to display more than only these 2 fields then can I use like `var sire = $('#Sire').val();`

Comment: Yes. And then you just append more `<td>` element to to row based on your form controls

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved my problem. Can you please tell me difference between this approach `$('#partial').html(response);` and `var row = $('<tr></tr>');` appending the data. Which one is good for which circumstances?

Comment: `$('#partial').html(response);` means you need to return a partial view from the controller method (and in your case, that would be a partial view based on `IEnumerable<T>` that generates your table). In you case, that is unnecessary, since all you need to do is add one new row to the table, and you already have all the necessary information in the view to do that (i.e. based on the form controls)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're not include `response.success` in JSON response, hence it always returns `false` and `$('#partial').html(response)` never executes. You should use `PartialView` for success response like this:

```
public ActionResult HorseTracker(ClsHorseTracker model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            horseTrackerDetails.InsertUpdateHorseTracker(model);
        }
        return PartialView("_pHorseTrackerDetails", model)
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Your message here" });
    }
}
```

And then change your AJAX POST to retrieve HTML response as given below:

```
$.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
    if (response.success == false) {
        var message = response.message;
        alert(message);
    }
    else {
        debugger;
        $('#partial').html(response);
    }
});
```

If you want to returning viewmodel contents with result status instead, you must append HTML table rows and cell elements manually with `$.each`:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult HorseTracker(ClsHorseTracker model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            horseTrackerDetails.InsertUpdateHorseTracker(model);
        }
        return Json(new { success = true, data = model });
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Your message here" });
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post(url,$(this).serialize(), function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        debugger;
            $.each(response.data, function(i, item) {
                var row = $('<tr>');
                row.append($('<td>').text(item.HorseName), $('<td>').text(item.HorseTypeName));
            });
            $('#table').append(row);
    }
    else {
        var message = response.message;
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your first approach gives error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ClsHorseTracker', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ClsHorseTracker]'.`